# ASF::Client::ClientConnectException: Client received error with operation get_segments on service SegmentRead version 1.0 endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

My application was working and has unexpectedly stopped working. Even the recommended PayPal demo downloaded from git-hub seems to not be working. I'm not finding much about this problem and am hoping someone here can lend a hand.

The Express Checkout initializes and transfers the user to the PayPal log in. Once logged in, PayPal displays an error that starts with "ASF::Client::ClientConnectException: Client received error with operation get_segments on service SegmentRead version 1.0 endpoint..." and the transaction is halted. Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your host is blocking the call to PayPal......

Generally for shared hosting (who have not purchased/rented dedicated Application pool), hosting companies block third party calls like the one of PayPal in your case......

But also before accusing the hosting company try this following two things first:

a) clear your browser cache.Paypal developer section has been under updation.And youw testing web app still might be using the older url from the cache.

b) Create new Test buyer/seller account and try out.You can import the older test accounts in the new paypal developer version too.

With these two steps am sure you will get rid of the issue you are facing.

I was facing same error and now its working fine after conducting above two steps.